# Cannot install remote marketplace locations

Tags: eclipse

I cannot install software nor open marketplace

Error details:

[image]

Comment: Is there a proxy of some kind you need to authenticate through?

Comment: `3: <TITLE>Kerberos V5 Authentication Redirection</TITLE>` ← looks like something (Kerberos V5) is modifying the response of the HTTP request of the Eclipse Marketplace Client causing this issue.

Comment: In case you are using a very old Eclipse version, you might run into [Eclipse bug 511226](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=511226).